# How do I use the defer render functionality with my datatable

Tags: c#, jquery, json, datatable, deferred-rendering

I have a datatable i wish to use defer render on, I am not sure what the issue is, my controller method returns an array of json objects. See code below.

**Datatable setup **

This is called when the page is loaded.

```
        var $dtTable = $("#tblPlayer");
        $dtTable.dataTable({
            bFilter: false,
            pageLength: 10,
            paging: true,
            autoWidth: true,
            columns:
            [
                null,
                { "orderDataType": "dom-text", type: "string" },
                { "orderDataType": "dom-text", type: "string" },
                { "orderDataType": "dom-text-numeric" },
                { "orderDataType": "dom-text-numeric" },
                { "orderDataType": "dom-text-numeric" },
                { "orderDataType": "dom-text-numeric" },
                { "orderDataType": "dom-text-numeric" },
                null,
                null,
                null
            ],
            "ajax": "Player/GetSetPlayers",
            "deferRender": true
        });
```

**Controller methods**

```
    public object[] GetSetPlayers()
    {
        var players = GetPlayers();

        _players = new object[players.Count];

        for (var i = 0; i < players.Count; i++)
        {
            _players[i] = players[i];
        }
        return _players;
    }
```

`GetSetPlayers()` returns an array of json objects, the result below is an exampel of what index 0 and 1 will contain.

**Response**

```
[  
   {  
      "product":25000,
      "rank":1,
      "dirty_money":25000,
      "id":"b4b41b18edbb49b9ae80be5e768b6b80",
      "name":"Dan",
      "ban_status":0,
      "edit":"<a href='/support/player_gamedata/b4b41b18edbb49b9ae80be5e768b6b80/game' class='btn'><i class='icon-folder-close'></i></a>",
      "credit":30,
      "clean_money":20000,
      "ban":"<a href='/support/ban_player/by_id/b4b41b18edbb49b9ae80be5e768b6b80/' class='btn'><i class='icon-remove'></i></a>",
      "supplies":25000
   },
   {  
      "product":25000,
      "rank":1,
      "dirty_money":25000,
      "id":"3cac6e366170458686021eaa77ac4d6d",
      "name":"Dan",
      "ban_status":0,
      "edit":"<a href='/support/player_gamedata/3cac6e366170458686021eaa77ac4d6d/game' class='btn'><i class='icon-folder-close'></i></a>",
      "credit":30,
      "clean_money":20000,
      "ban":"<a href='/support/ban_player/by_id/3cac6e366170458686021eaa77ac4d6d/' class='btn'><i class='icon-remove'></i></a>",
      "supplies":25000
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify a "data" attribute on each column that needs to be populated from the returned data.  Otherwise it doesn't know what attribute on the json object goes to each column.  If you defined your data as an array of arrays instead of an array of objects this wouldn't be required.

Additionally you aren't specifying a "dataSrc" option which isn't required but if it isn't set I believe it expects the returned JSON to be of the form:

```
{
  data: [ {...}, {...} ]
}
```

So it would be helpful if you could add in the raw response to the ajax request.

**EDIT1:**

Ok so double checked and yes it does want an object array assigned to the "data" attribute on the JSON object so you can do something like this to fix this without having to modify anything on the server.  Just change your ajax option to this:

```
"ajax": {
  "url": "Player/GetSetPlayers",
  "dataSrc": function ( json ) {
      // We need override the built in dataSrc function with one that will 
      // just return the object array instead of looking for a "data" 
      // attribute on the "json" object.  Note if you ever want to add 
      // serverside sorting/filtering/paging you will need to move your table 
      // data to an attribute within the JSON object.
      return json;
   }
}
```

So you will probably be good once you do both of the fixes above.

Comment: @ife labolz  Did you try running this with the "data" attribute set on each of the columns that are going to have data?  It is just " data: 'jsonAttrName', ".